# Acentos y caracteres latinos en Django

Tags: html, python, django

Tengo un problema con Django, aunque tengo en mi plantilla html el siguiente código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Página de prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Esto es una página de prueba</h1><br>
        Página de prueba para Python
    </body>
</html>
```

Cuando inicio el servidor Django, me aparece de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea sobre cómo arreglarlo?
Edito con nueva idea que me dio @Christian, pero sigue dándome el mismo error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Página de prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Esto es una página de prueba</h1><br>
        Página de prueba para Python
    </body>
</html>
```

Gracias a la respuesta de @Danny, el código queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Página de prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Esto es una página de prueba</h1><br>
        Página de prueba para Python
    </body>
</html>
```

Y funciona a la perfección:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas, y en especial a @Danny :D.

Comment: En la etiqueta `html` debes especificar el encoding

Comment: @Christian de que manera podría hacerlo?

Comment: Perdón me equivoqué, era en la etiqueta `meta` de esta forma `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Buenas @Christian , he editado como me has dicho, pero me sigue dando el mismo error. Arriba he editado el post para que veas como lo he hecho. Un saludo.

Comment: Es recomendable que en la etiqueta html, tengas añadido en que idioma se encuentra, esto puede ayudar a que no surjan errores como estos, aun que puede que no termine de solucionar tu problema, es una buena practica en el etiquetado.   *<html lang="es">*

Comment: @amtamv Parece que no ha podido solucionar el problema, pero lo tendré en cuenta como buena práctica. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: Buenas @BetaM , lo que proponen en ese post parece ser que ya lo he aplicado. Muchas gracias por tu aportación :D!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta agregando la etiqueta: `<!DOCTYPE html>` antes de `<html>` esta etiqueta le dice al navegador en qué versión de HTML esta escrito el archivo y así mismo le dices al navegador que debe esperar.

Comment: Perfecto! Me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias!